# How to close the quill editor when done with editing

Tags: javascript, quill

I am dynamically instantiating the QuillJS editor on a click event of an element in the DOM. So my requirement is that once the user is done with the editing for that element, he/she should be able to close the editor. Currently, I do not see any close method in the quill API. The enable/disable API methods won't work for me as I want to close the editor completely and show the user the same view he/she had before seeing the quill editor but of course with the saved changes.

The demo of this can be seen here
https://codepen.io/curiousdj/pen/eEjbPK

```
const options = { theme: "snow" };
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var initializeQuill = function (e){
     if(!this.quill){
        console.log(e);
        this.target = event.currentTarget;
        this.quill = new Quill(this.target, options);
        this.target.children[0].onclick = function(et) { et.preventDefault(); };
        this.target.children[0].onblur = function(l) {
               l.target.parentElement.quill.close;
         };
        }
        this.quill.focus();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
}
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    divs[i].onclick = initializeQuill;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd advise either:

1. Copy the contents of the quill instance, destroy the DOM element that the instance is bound to, create a new DOM element and paste the contents back in
2. Use disable via the API as you've already tried, but also style disabled Quill instances to not show any differentiation between Quill's formatting and your own.

I've updated your pen [here](https://codepen.io/Joeao/pen/BdOGKV) to give an example of the second option with basic changes

```
.ql-editor {
  padding:0;
  line-height:inherit;
}

.ql-editor p {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.ql-toolbar {
  display:none;
}

.ql-container.ql-snow {
  border:none;
  font-family:inherit;
  font-size:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
function destory_editor(selector){
    if($(selector)[0])
    {
        var content = $(selector).find('.ql-editor').html();
        $(selector).html(content);

        $(selector).siblings('.ql-toolbar').remove();
        $(selector + " *[class*='ql-']").removeClass (function (index, css) {
           return (css.match (/(^|\s)ql-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
        });

        $(selector + "[class*='ql-']").removeClass (function (index, css) {
           return (css.match (/(^|\s)ql-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.error('editor not exists');
    }
}
```

To use it just call:

```
destory_editor('.editor');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting `contenteditable="false"` on the content div.

Comment: Hey @Roshan, contenteditable wont help in this context, as my use case requires to close the editor after the editing is complete. So I am looking for an event I can call onblur or such.

Answer (score 0):

On the latest version (and perhaps previous versions) the `ql-toolbar` is always the `previousSibling` of the quill editor. So removing the toolbar becomes as simple as;

```
document.getElementById("editor element id").previousSibling.remove();
```

This has the benefit of *"disposing"* one editor at a time.

Answer (score 0):

So I logged the entire `quill` object and went through all instances of **toolbar**, **tooltip** and **clipboard** in order to find a cleaner way to remove these from the DOM.

I discovered that the right paths to be as follows:

- `quill.theme.modules.toolbar.container`
- `quill.theme.modules.clipboard.container`
- `quill.theme.tooltip.root`

So there is a cleaner method to destroy quill:

```js
function destroy_quill(quill, el) {

    // remove toolbox
    quill.theme.modules.toolbar.container.remove();
    // remove clipboard
    quill.theme.modules.clipboard.container.remove();
    // remove tooltip
    quill.theme.tooltip.root.remove();

    // remove all unwanted classes
    el.classList.forEach((cls) => {
      if (cls.startsWith("ql-")) {
        // we use requestAnimationFrame because there's a limit to how fast browsers will run dom manipulations
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          el.classList.remove(cls);
        });
      }
    });

    // set inner html
    el.innerHTML = quill.root.innerHTML

}

// call with instances of quill and your element
destroy_quill(quill, el);
```